# How to insert image using openxml?

Tags: openxml-sdk

How to insert image into a word document where a word document consist of a table,that image should be inserted in one of the table cell how to do that?please help me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check [How to: Insert a picture into a word processing document (Open XML SDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497430%28v=office.15%29.aspx) article at MSDN . It will help you on `inserting images` to word docuemnt.

Also [Working with WordprocessingML tables (Open XML SDK)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278313%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and [How to: Insert a Table into a Word Processing Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850841%28v=office.14%29.aspx) will help you on working with `Tables` in OpenXml.

**Update :**

I assume you get your desired cell in the document by th code mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850841(v=office.14).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-6 (so you have your TableCell in **`tc2`** variable) , And also I assume you have added your desired image to document by the code mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb497430(v=office.15).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-5 (so you have image refrence in **`element`** varialbe)

so simply run this code to add the image to your **tc2** table cell :

```
tc2.AppendChild(new Paragraph(new Run(element)));
```

Comment: but i need to insert image into table cell sir can u please help meout?

Comment: Can you access your TableCell? I mean can you get your table cell in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

The question is old and I think whoever asked has found a way to add an image into a table's cell, but I will share my code with any want might find it useful in the future.

```py
# We need to iterate through:
            # rows       'tr_lst' then ->
            # cells      'tc_lst' then ->
            # paragraphs 'p_lst'  then ->
            # runs       'r_lst'  then checks if the run has text if not then check its XML if contains required rId
            for _tbl_row in _table.tr_lst:
                for _row_cell in _tbl_row.tc_lst:
                    for _cell_paragraph in _row_cell.p_lst:
                        for _cell_run in _cell_paragraph.r_lst:
                            if _cell_run.text == "":
                                if _rid in _cell_run.xml:
                                    image_path = _path
                                    docx__paragraph = Paragraph(_cell_paragraph, our_table._parent)
                                    #our_table is the same as the table itself before accessing its protected attribute "_tbl"
                                    # This run is considered corrupted which is why need to delete it and then add a new one
                                    _run = docx__paragraph.runs[0]._element
                                    _run.getparent().remove(_run)
                                    _run._r = _run._element = None
                                    # New run contains only an image therefore we don't need to add additional info.
                                    docx__paragraph.add_run().add_picture(image_path)
```